# D3js legend color does not match to the map color javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, leaflet, folium

I have a map already drawed. I would like to add a legend using d3.js. For example when filering by length, the map should show differents colors. Since a week, I couldn't achieve this task. My map color seem to be good but the legend does not match.
Could anybody help me with my draw link function ?
https://jsfiddle.net/aba2s/xbn9euh0/12/)

I think it's the error is about the legend function.
Here is the function that change my map color `Roads.eachLayer(function (layer) {layer.setStyle({fillColor: colorscale(layer.feature.properties.length)})});`

```
function drawLinkLegend(dataset, colorscale, min, max) {
    // Show label
    linkLabel.style.display = 'block'

    var legendWidth = 100
        legendMargin = 10
        legendLength = document.getElementById('legend-links-container').offsetHeight - 2*legendMargin
        legendIntervals = Object.keys(colorscale).length
        legendScale = legendLength/legendIntervals

    // Add legend

    var legendSvg = d3.select('#legend-links-svg')
                .append('g')
                .attr("id", "linkLegendSvg");

    var bars = legendSvg.selectAll(".bars")
      //.data(d3.range(legendIntervals), function(d) { return d})
      .data(dataset)
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bars")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", function(d, i) { return legendMargin + legendScale * (legendIntervals - i-1); })
        .attr("height", legendScale)
        .attr("width", legendWidth-50)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return colorscale(d) })

    // create a scale and axis for the legend
    var legendAxis = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([min, max])
        .range([legendLength, 0]);

    legendSvg.append("g")
         .attr("class", "legend axis")
         .attr("transform", "translate(" + (legendWidth - 50) + ", " + legendMargin + ")")
         .call(d3.axisRight().scale(legendAxis).ticks(10))
}
```

Comment: Please, help me, Do you think, it's about my `data(d3.range(legendIntervals), function(d) { return d})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 expects your data array to represent the elements you are creating. It appears you are passing an array of all  your features: but you want your scale to represent intervals. It looks like you have attempted this approach, but you haven't quite got it.

We want to access the minimum and maximum values that will be provided to the scale. To do so we can use `scale.domain()` which returns an array containing the extent of the domain, the min and max values.

We can then create a dataset that contains values between (and including) these two endpoints.

Lastly, we can calculate their required height based on how high the visual scale is supposed to be by dividing the height of the visual scale by the number of values/intervals.

Then we can supply this information to the enter/update/exit cycle. The enter/update/exit cycle expects one item in the data array for every element in the selection - hence why need to create a new dataset.

Something like the following shold work:

```
var dif = colorscale.domain()[1] - colorscale.domain()[0];
var intervals = d3.range(20).map(function(d,i) {
    return dif * i / 20 + colorscale.domain()[0]
}) 
intervals.push(colorscale.domain()[1]);
var intervalHeight = legendLength / intervals.length;
 
var bars = legendSvg.selectAll(".bars")
  .data(intervals)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bars")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) { return Math.round((intervals.length - 1 - i)  * intervalHeight) + legendMargin; })
    .attr("height", intervalHeight)
    .attr("width", legendWidth-50)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colorscale(d) })
```

*In troubleshooting your existing code, you can see you have too many elements in the DOM when representing the scale. Also, `Object.keys(colorscale).length` won't produce information useful for generating intervals - the keys of the scale are not dependent on the data.*

[eg](https://jsfiddle.net/5ptfuqk9/)

Comment: Lots of thanks, that's what I was looking for. What do you mean by "D3 expects your data array to represent the elements you are creating. It appears you are passing an array of all your features: but you want your scale to represent intervals" Could you plus show it by the script line for my curiosity? Sorry I am new in d3js and javascript.

Comment: A key factor in the creation of D3 was data binding - binding data from the data array to elements in the DOM. Generally one item in the data array is matched to one element (or set of elements) in the DOM. The visual representation of the scale has intervals that are independent of the road features: the scale has the same number of intervals regardless of if the number of features is 2 or a million - so to keep a 1:1 relationship between data and element we need to create a new dataset (the original features dataset might not have one feature per interval, it could have more or less).

Comment: Do you know how can I disapear white line between legend color?